# Get current route name of CupertinoTabView in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using `CupertinoTabScaffold` and `CupertinoTabView` to build navigation bottom bar in my App. For one `CupertinoTabView` I go to others pushed routes name, I would like to get the current name of a `CupertinoTabView`, but I get `Null`

I define the routes in main like that

```
CupertinoApp(
        home: MyApp(),
        title: 'machin',
        routes: appRoutes,)

final appRoutes = {
  '/pushedName': (context) => PushedName(),
};
```

MyApp class //

```
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> profileTabNavKey =
      GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

 CupertinoTabScaffold(
          tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(

            activeColor: Color(0xff077018),
            border: Border.all(color: Color(0xffffffff)),
            currentIndex: widget.currentIndex,
            onTap: (index) {},
            items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[....],
          ),
          tabBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            switch (index) {
              
     
              case 0:
                return CupertinoTabView(
                    navigatorKey: profileTabNavKey,
          
                     routes: appRoutes,
                    builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                  SettingsView());
                break;
              default:
                return HomePage();
            }
          },
        ),
```

In the `SettingsView` I pushed a named route by using

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/pushedName')
```

I tried to get the route name in the my app class by using

```
print(ModalRoute.of(profileTabNavKey.currentContext).settings.name);
```

nb: in the `pushedName` View i get it perfectly any help , thanks in advance

Comment: Please add PushedName class code snippet.

Comment: the problem is not in pushedName, its just a simple where i showed the current view

Answer (score 3):

Just use the `BuildContext` from the build widget to get the `ModalRoute` data :

```
ModalRoute.of(context).settings.name
```

Working example :

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: CupertinoTheme.of(context).copyWith(
        brightness: Brightness.light,
      ),
      home: MainPage(),
    );
  }
}

class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainPageState createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  int currentIndex = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoTabScaffold(
      tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(
        currentIndex: currentIndex,
        onTap: (index) {
          setState(() {
            currentIndex = index;
          });
        },
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            label: 'Home',
            icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.home),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            label: 'Setting',
            icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.settings),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      tabBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        switch (index) {
          case 1:
            return CupertinoTabView(
              routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
                '/setting': (context) => SettingsPage(),
                '/setting/2': (context) => SettingsPage(2),
                '/setting/2/3': (context) => SettingsPage(3),
              },
              builder: (context) => SettingsPage(),
            );
            break;
          default:
            return Center(
              child: Text('Home page'),
            );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}

class SettingsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final int index;

  SettingsPage([this.index = 1]);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // here we go to get the current route name
    print(ModalRoute.of(context).settings.name);

    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
        backgroundColor: CupertinoColors.systemGrey.withOpacity(0.5),
        middle: Text(index > 1 ? 'Settings page - $index' : 'Settings page'),
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: CupertinoButton.filled(
          child: Text('Go'),
          onPressed: () {
            if (index == 1) {
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/setting/2');
            } else if (index == 2) {
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/setting/2/3');
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Go to [Dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/3a628f7139b575b42ef99213312c1112)

Comment: thanks for your comment , I want to access to     print(ModalRoute.of(context).settings.name); in tabBuilder , i get always /

Comment: or in another way i want to access to this route name in navigation bottom bar before switching to another tab

Comment: You need to define all routes for every widget page to show. Otherwise you will always see the default [Navigator.defaultRouteName](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/defaultRouteName-constant.html) which reflects the route that the application was started with.

Comment: if i define all routes names , i will get the pushed name above of a CupertinoTabBar in tabBuilder ?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that doesn't sound like best practice, but it works!

Instead of using `ModalRouter` and other libraries like `navigation_history_observer`, I used `Navigator.popUntil` and blocked the popup from getting the current route from the argument and assigned it to a variable.

```
WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: () async {
    String currentRoute;

    navigatorKeys[_tabController.index].currentState.popUntil((route) {
      currentRoute = route.settings.name;
      return true;
    });

    if (currentRoute == '/') {
      return Future.value(false);
    } else {
      return !await navigatorKeys[_tabController.index]
          .currentState
          .maybePop();
    }
  },

  // ...
);
```